# What's the correct way to implement the ellipse equation in C?

Tags: c, geometry, render, equation, ellipse

I am trying to render ellipse on  plotter powered by an MCU so there is low memory to work with and integer arithmetics is preffered.

I've got this equation

[image: elipse equation]

and I tried to implement it in C in the following way:

```
y = sqrt( (b*b) * ( 1 - ( (x*x) / (a*a) )));
```

where `y`, `b`, `x` and `a` are integer values but the results where wrong .

**Q1 Is this correct implementation of ellipse equation?**

**Q2 Are there any other ways to do this?**

Comment: Note:  integer division will result in truncation.  You may want to convert to floating point.

Comment: `sqrt` will return a double, why does y have to be an integer?

Comment: Please give details about why your program is not working, especially the code. **DO NOT POST CODE IN COMMENTS, EDIT YOUR POST WITH THE CODE.**

Comment: it should be plotted with a plotter (which has only integer coordinates)

Comment: my programm returns only b or 0 thats the problem

Comment: @Mattis in that case perform the calculation with doubles, and **then** use the rounded result of the calculation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Don't yell. Just vote to close and move on.

Comment: @n.m. hmm if he need pixel perfect rendering then your way will not guarantee this unless using sub-pixel precision before final transformation... It is more precise and usually faster to interpolate in the target device coordinates from the beginning.

Comment: @Spektre yes my bad, interpolation should be done in target coordinates.

Comment: Note: there exists a dual differential engine implementation ("Bresenham") for ellipses.

Comment: @Mattis: I edited the formatting of your question but somehow I fail to see the *question*. Please check my edit just in case I deleted it.

Comment: @Jongware yes you removed some vital info ... I added it back and added some things from comments also to clarify

Comment: @Spektre: I don't think I actually *removed* anything, the question was stated very badly. So it was meant as an oblique hint for the OP ...

Comment: @Jongware Yes you're right I see the edits all the info was in comments (I tought it was in Question body but that was different question not this one) sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **for plotting the ellipse (outline by lines) is the parametric equation the best.**

   Here axis aligned ellipse:

   ```
   x=x0+a*cos(t);
   y=y0+b*sin(t);
   ```

   where:

   - `(x0,y0)` is the ellipse center
   - `a,b` are the semi-axises
   - `t` is angular parameter `t=<0,2*M_PI>`

     1. So form a loop where `t` goes the full circle with some small enough step
     2. compute `(x,y)` per each step of t
     3. interpolate/render line per each step (from last to new point)

   as your `x,y,x0,y0,a,b` are integers either convert them to float/double or create integer table for `cos[],sin[]` for example:

   - `int tcos[360],tsin[360];`

   where  `tcos[i]=float(1000.0*cos(float(i)*M_PI/180.0));` now on use just integers like:

   ```
   for (i=0;i<360;i++)
    {
    x=x0+(a*tcos(i))/1000;
    y=y0+(b*tsin(i))/1000;
    //...
    }
   ```
2. **If you need pixel perfect rendering or render filled ellipse**

   Then you need use different approach (the same as your equation)

   1. loop one axis with pixel step
   2. compute the other axis coordinate
   3. render both pixels/or fill the line

   for example axis aligned `(0,0)` centered ellipse:

   ```
   for (x=-a;x<=a;x++)
    {
    y = sqrt( (b*b) - ( (x*x*b*b) / (a*a) )));
    // render pixels: (x,+y) and (x,-y) or join them by line
    }
   ```

   if you need integer `sqrt` then implement one (instead of using `math.h`) for example:

   ```
   int bits(DWORD p)
       {
       DWORD m=0x80000000; int b=32;
       for (;m;m>>=1,b--)
        if (p>=m) break;
       return b;
       }

   DWORD sqrt(const DWORD &x)
       {
       DWORD m,a;
       m=(bits(x)>>1); // bits(x) just return position of MSB nonzero bit can use m=16; instead
       if (m) m=1<<m; else m=1;
       for (a=0;m;m>>=1) { a|=m; if (a*a>x) a^=m; }
       return a;
       }
   ```

   where `DWORD` is unsigned 32 bit int data type.
3. **for filling you do not need the sqrt**

   You can instead loop through the area and decide if the pixel is inside or not:

   ```
   for (y=-b;y<=b;y++)
    for (x=-a;x<=a;x++)
     if ( (y*y) <= ( (b*b) - ( (x*x*b*b) / (a*a) ) ) )
      // render pixel: (x,y)
   ```

Comment: @Mattis The `tsin,tcos` tables can have just few steps (usually 96 is more then enough so for 32bit ints that is 768B total. and the `1000` can be `1024` so use bitshift instead. There are also integer sin and cos approximations out there so no need for tables in that case. Bresenham is also an option but if you need to preserve the order of pixels (like plotters do) then that would need even bigger buffers to store the points. If you need pixel perfect ellipse then #2 is your only option I can think of (due to additional constrains you introduced)

Comment: @Mattis btw how do you making motion planning? Do you have own interpolator inside MCU? or use motion processor per motor? or use analog control? or use servos instead all of this? ... nice to see someone get dirty with real HW these days

Answer (score -1):

The implementation is correct. I set y,b,x and a as double values this fixed the wrong output.

Comment: no it is not it will work also on integers if you multiply the therm by the `(b*b)` term to get rid of the `()` now you got decent number after the division (originally you got something less then `1` which is on integer `0` or `1` ) Always first multiply and divide at the end on integers. (on floats also to not loose precision) See my answer I got few implementations for you this one included

Comment: You're right and your solution might be effective, but my plotter is powered by an microcontroller with only a few KB's of RAM so i can't calculate all values before i plot, because this would'nt work with that less ram. b will be always an integer because i'm converting cm (from the input) to steps (for plotting). So it will usally be something like between 5000 and 1 (if it is 0 i cant plot an ellipse anyway). AND yes I should have added this details to my question.